# Floating/Popover Image

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, html, material-design

I am trying to create a card like the one shown in the image. However I am not able to create the floating image on the card. Any guidance with how to achieve the effect using angular, jquery, css or any free plugin with sample code would be appreciated.

[image: Card Image]

Currently I am using materialize framework.

The code I have used to create a card is this:

`

```
<div class="col s6">
                        <div class="card card white lighten-1 horizontal" style="height: 300px; width: 500px;">
                        <div class="card-image">
                        <img src="assets/dark_murder.jpg">
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-content grey-text">
                        <span class="card-title">Dark Murder</span>
                        <div class='starrr' id='star1'></div>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer  adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.</p>
                        <div class="card-action">
                        <a href="#">This is a link</a>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                      </div> 

`

The css is this:
`
.card-image img {
 position: absolute;
    bottom: 8px;
    left: 16px;
    height: 100%;
}
.card-title {
  padding-left: 20px;
}`
```

and I have achieved this:
[Card so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/12ceI.png)

Answer (score 0):

you can easily create using bootstrap.

**HTML**

```
<div class="card-content">
   <h2> Ttitle goes here</h2>
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
      consectetur adipiscing elit, 
      sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut 
      labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
      <a href=""> Cleck here to read more</a>
 </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.card {
  background-color: #bdbdbd;
  margin: 30px 0;
  padding: 30px 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

check a demo : http://codepen.io/sifulislam/pen/XjrajE

Comment: I need the image to  be floating out of the card as shown in the image.